# ga:YearWeek is different then =isoweeknum

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-analytics, google-sheets-formula, week-number

I'm reading Google Analytics data into Google Sheets. The metric is `ga:YearWeek` - its current value is `201945`.

But, if i try to get the current week number using `=isoweeknum(201945)` i get `48` instead of `45`, which isn't correct value.

Ortherwise, if i use `=isoweeknum(2019-11-04)` i get correctly `45`. What i'm doing wrong on querying `=isoweeknum(201945)`? I need `45`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing it as a value so the date is far away in future...

value `201945` is equal to date: `25/11/2452`
while date `2019-4-5` is equal to value: `43560`

so yes, `=ISOWEEKNUM(201945)` to return `48` is correct value because the year is **2452**

Comment: funny... This value i get from GA. Could you recommend, how should i manipulate the date i'm getting from Google Analytics to get correct week number?

Comment: try simple: `=MID(A2, 5, 2)` https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT6Iq.png or `=MID(201945, 5, 2)`